# sql result in php matrix according sorted by branches/product/size

Tags: php, sql

I've been trying hard to figure out how to do matrix from the result of an sql query where the x is location, y is the size/description and the data filling are the quantities available in each location according to the size and color.

I have it done using pl/sql but not php. I want to transform the forms to a web layout in order to access it from anywhere. 
the query is:

```
    $q5="select  artdesc DECRIPTON ,  ARTUPRB PRICE$ ,depcode LOCATION,  ARDQTDIS
          QUANTITY from fgart a, fgartdep b where a.soccode='01' and artfam =:fam and 
    artdiv=:div  and artsec=:sec  and artsubsec =:subsec and 
         (EXISTS 
     (select distinct artserial from fgart   where soccode ='01' and artsec =:sec 
     and artsubsec =:subsec and artfoucode =:wartfoucode   and artserial = a.artserial)    
         or EXISTS 
    (select distinct artfoucode from fgart where    soccode ='01' and artsec =:sec and 
    artsubsec =:subsec and artfoucode = a.artfoucode and  artserial =:wserial))
    and 
    b.soccode ='01' and b.bracode ='01' and a.artcode = b.artcode 
     and   depcode  <> '99'
       AND ARDQTDIS <> '0' 
         order by artdesc";
```

I have a small query prior of this one where I catch all the variables and pass them to the above sql.
I have managed to do a normal listing using the below code:

```
    <?php
    $r7=oci_parse($oconn,$q5);
    $r8 = oci_execute($r7);
    sleep(100); 
    if (oci_execute($r7)){ 
    usleep(100); 
    print "<TABLE border \"1\" cellpadding=\"3%\">"; 
    $first = 0; 
    while ($row = @oci_fetch_assoc($r7)){ 
            if (!$first){ 
                    $first = 1; 
                    echo ("<TR> <TH bgcolor=\"#FF9900\" > <font color=\"FFFFFF\">" ); 
                    echo( implode("</TH><TH bgcolor=\"#FF9900\">", array_keys($row))); 
                    echo ("</TH> </TR> </font> \n"); 
            } 
            echo ("<TR><TD bgcolor=\"#D0D0D0\" >"); 
    echo (@implode("</TD> <TD bgcolor=\"#F0F0F0\">",str_replace ($Woutl,  Wdesc,
    array_values($row))));  
            echo ("</TD> </TR>\n"); 
    } 
    echo ("</TABLE>"); 
    ?>
```

Please if anyone can direct me the right track in order to get result similar to the below:

```
              location (x) :         dt    sk    abc    ss
    Item desc /size (y):
    blue  46                         2      1     0     4
    blue  48                         1      1     1     0   
    blue  50                         0      0     2     1    
    grey  44                         5      1     1     1
    grey  46                         4      1     1     1       
    grey  50                         3      2     2     0
```

Comment: I don't understand. Can't you just use the html table, th, td and tr in order to achieve that?

Comment: its not that obvious, I tried to but the locations are variables and sometimes they are 4 and other query might returns up to 15 locations, same for the items/description.